# Lme4 syntax for mixed model

Tags: r

I have $m=4$ group of mice (i.e group1, group2, group3, group4). Each group has a different number of mice. I measure a parameter $(y)$ on each mice of each group at $l=4$ different states (i.e state1, state2, state3, state4). I would like to build a mixed effect model to analyse the effect of group, state and group*state, allowing for the variability within each mouse and within each group.The mice within $group_{m}$ are labeled with an id (1,2,3...,number of mice of $group_{m}$)

$$y_{mln}=\mu +group_{m} +state_{l} +(group*state)*{ml}+b*{ml}+\varepsilon_{mln} 
$$
with $b_{ml}$ the random effect for the nth mouse within $group_{m}$

My data frame has the following variables

```
value (num)
state (factor: 4 levels)
group (factor: 4 levels)
id (within group) (num)
```

Is the corresponding syntax correct?

```
lmer(value~group+state+group*state+(1|group))
```

Comment: @gung Thanks for your comment. I wasn't sure which place is the most appropriate. Please feel free to migrate my question.

Comment: @ECII As stated, your model only considers a random intercept for group; `id` does not appear in your formula. We can migrate this question for you if you like, but if you are concerned with the design of this experiment and you do have a specific statistical question it should be easy to update your post so that it fits within the scope of this site.

Comment: @chi I think you are right that my question is more technical than "statistical". Please migrate my question.

Comment: In the question you mention you're interested in the interaction between group and state, but your formula has `group*time`. Are `time` and `state` the same? Also, as chl asked, what role does `id` play? (Unrelated: does `LaTeX` coding not work in SO?)

Comment: Time and state are the same. I have corrected it. id is the identification of each mouse in the group.And apparently SO does not understand LaTeX. My post sucks (aesthetically)

Comment: I don't know how to answer your full question, but in model formulas, '`a*b`' is shorthand for '`a + b + a:b`', so you should never need to write `a + b + a*b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this

```
mouseID <- interaction(group, ID)
lmer(value ~ group * state + (1|mouseID))
```

The mouseID must be unique for each mouse.

Since group is a factor, you can't have it both in the fixed and the random part. That would lead to an unidentifiable model.

Comment: To allow for the non-unique coding of `mouseID` you can use `(1|group:mouseID)`. If you want to treat `group` as random rather than a fixed effect (which might not work very well with only 4 groups, despite its potential conceptual justification) you would use `value~state+(state|group)+(1|group:mouseID)`: `(state|group)` adds a random (intercept) effect of group and a state-by-group interaction (which is also random).

Comment: Thanks Thierry and Ben for the clarifications. Great comments. I find mixed model approaches are a bit hazy in R. Could you recommend me perhaps some reading material?

Comment: I enjoyed reading Zuur et al (2009) http://www.springer.com/life+sciences/ecology/book/978-0-387-87457-9

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is

```
lmer(value ~ group*state + (1|group) + (1|id))
```

This model estimates the fixed effect of group and state as well as the interaction between them (`R` automatically expands `group*state` to `group + state + group*state`) and estimates a random intercept for the effect of each group and for each mouse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am having difficulties wrapping my mind arround the syntax of lme4. What would be in your syntax different than in mine? Why and how to they differ?

Comment: Your syntax doesn't include `(1|id)`, the between-mouse variance (assuming that each mouse has its own unique `id`).

Comment: Not really. In my data set the id identifies the mouse within this group. Group1 has 12 mice (with ids 1,2,3...12), group 2 has 6 mice (with id 1,2,3...6). id serves to identify each mouse within the group (since this mouse will have 3 measurements at the 3 states). The between mouse variace that you are talking about is it between groups or within states? Thank you for your time.

Comment: (I thought there were 4 states?) If different mice in different groups can have the same `id` then the model as I described it doesn't make sense. However, if you code the `id` so that each mouse in the data has a unique `id`, then the `(1|id)` term is the overall mouse-to-mouse variability, regardless of group or state.

Comment: @Ben, is this possible in mixed models? In lme4? I can feel the difference from what smillig has written, however cannot imagine the difference of the models in the bayesian (or mathematical) model notation...